# Как исправить ошибку с context java android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть класс Questions.java, в котором инициализирую массивы строк (данные беру из resources strings).
Т.к. нужен context для получения Strings Resources, я передаю его в конструктор класса Questions.java, когда создаю экземпляр в активности MainActivity:
**MainActivity.java**

```
HashMap<String, String[]> questions = new HashMap(); // словарь: ключ - строка, значение - массив строк из Questions.java
Questions q = new Questions(this);

questions.put(getResources().getString(R.string.question1), q.arr1);
questions.put(getResources().getString(R.string.question2), q.arr2);
questions.put(getResources().getString(R.string.question3), q.arr3);
```

**Questions.java**

```
package ru.examplle.pravmin;
import ru.examplle.pravmin.R;
import android.content.Context;

public class Questions {
    private Context context;

    public Questions(Context cur) {
        this.context = cur;
    }


    String[] arr1 = {context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer1_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer2_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer3_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer4_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.right_answer_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_for_question1)};
    String[] arr2 = {context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer1_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer2_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer3_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer4_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.right_answer_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_for_question2)};
    String[] arr3 = {context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer1_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer2_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer3_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer4_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.right_answer_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_for_question3)};
 }
```

Я в активности хочу брать эти массивы из класса Questions и с ними работать. Но при запуске приложения вылетает исключение:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at ru.examplle.pravmin.Questions.<init>(Questions.java:15) // строка String[] arr1 = {context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer1_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer2_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer3_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer4_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.right_answer_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_for_question1)};
        at ru.examplle.pravmin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:116) // строка Questions q = new Questions(this);
```

**Как исправить ошибку и запустить приложение?**

Answer (score 0):

Нестатические поля класса инициализируются раньше, чем конструктор, поэтому при иницализации обьекта класса Questions происходит ситуация, когда вы пытаетесь получить доступ к строковым ресурсам через переменную context, которая будет проинициализирована позже.

Как-то вот так сделайте например, что-ли:

```
public class Questions {
private Context context;
public String[] arr1;
public String[] arr2;
public String[] arr3;

public Questions(Context cur) {
    this.context = cur;
    this.arr1 = {context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer1_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer2_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer3_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer4_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.right_answer_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_for_question1)};
    this.arr2 = {context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer1_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer2_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer3_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer4_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.right_answer_for_question2), context.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_for_question2)};
    this.arr3 = {context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer1_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer2_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer3_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer4_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.right_answer_for_question3), context.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_for_question3)};
}
}
```

Comment: когда пишу `this.arr1 = {context.get....}`, то среда просит инициализировать массив (хоть я и сделал, как Вы и описали выше). `Array initializer is not allowed here`. Просит в таком виде записывать: `this.arr1 = new String[]{context.getResources....`, но вылетает аналогичное исключение: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Нужно добавить строки по каждому массиву this.arr1 - new String[4]; 4 - размерность массива

Comment: `public class Questions {
    private Context context;
    public String[] arr1 = new String[4];
    
    public Questions(Context cur) {
        this.context = cur;
        this.arr1 = {context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer1_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer2_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer3_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.answer4_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.right_answer_for_question1), context.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_for_question1)};
 }`

Comment: на строке `this.arr1 = {con..` пишет: `Array initializer is not allowed here` и просит сново инициализировать пустой массив: `this.arr1 = new String[]{context.getRes...`